# How to set 301 status code in actionResponse in Liferay MVC portlet

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

I have the following method in my MVC Portlet,

```
public void process(HttpServletRequest  actionRequest, HttpServletResponse  actionResponse){

   try
        {

   actionResponse.sendRedirect("https://www.sample.com/category/diamond?valid=true");
   actionResponse.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
}

catch(Exception ex){
System.out.println("Error occured" + ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

This redirects to the mentioned URL successfully but I want it to be a 301 redirection. So I tried

```
actionResponse.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
```

But it is not working, how can I do 301 redirection, can any one help me on that please.?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems to look at here,
First, check if you are not setting the code after send redirect commits the response.
Second, to set a code like that, you might want to try something like the following:

```
response.setProperty( ResourceResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE, Integer.toString( HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND ) );
```